# Is it possible to make certain parts of an image transparent in HTML5/CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to have an image on my page that has certain parts that are transparent, but not all of it. Is it possible to make just certain parts of an image/div transparent? For example, just a circle in the bottom right corner, or the top right portion?

Comment: You can not make a part of an image trasnparent using CSS (at the moment, there may be some masking capabilites in the future). You can ofcourse add transperancy to the image itself in `gif` and  `png` formats. PNG also supports partial transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this wonderful future world of 2022, you can now use [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) to achieve this type of effect:

```
img {
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 5%, black);
}
```

https://codepen.io/reynoldsalec/pen/OJOwZmV

Note that, although `mask-image` should be supported by all modern browsers, I've noticed that sometimes it needs to be prefixed (ex: `-webkit-mask-image`).

Comment: Thank you for a great answer, no less than seven years later. This future world is indeed wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/3a6b842v/)

Check this Demo, you can do by adding a span tag and give absolute position add opacity. and also you can increase the opacity.
Hope this is the one you are looking for. :)

**html :**

```
<div class="imgWrap">
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /> 
    <span class="tranparentClass"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.imgWrap img{
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #900;
}
.tranparentClass {
    opacity:.5;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    border-radius : 50%;
    display:block;
    padding:55px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;

}
```

Comment: The tranparentClass isn't transparent, it's just white. If I add a black background to the page, the tranparentClass is just white. You can't see through to the black background.

Comment: @Yajo100 : as per my understanding, if having a black background, add black background for transperency http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/r0f5ww0u/1/

Comment: I want this to work if the background changes or if the background is an image too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another CSS option. It simulates a transparent area within an image by sharing a fixed background with background-size:cover on both the *background* and the *circle*. This technique also creates interesting effects when used for other html elements that can have a background like divs, headers, paragraphs...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/q3c9r5b6/)

Main CSS

```
.main-background, .circle-div {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/1aAo20a.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center top;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="main-background">
    <div class="demo-holder">
        <img class="img-size" src="http://i.imgur.com/OaE8VAj.jpg" />
        <div class="circle-div">Transparent<br />Effect</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another suggestion would be to use the inline image as a background on "demo-holder".