# Load behind image on other images on boxes CSS jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i want to create web theme with this steps:

1 - Set a background image 
[First Step Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY480.jpg)
2 - Set other background image in the end picture
3 - Create circles or boxes and now load the part of image one as boxes background **(But how??? this is my question.)**

Code:

```
<style>
#Background_1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("img1.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        position: fixed;
    }

    #Background_2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("img2.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        z-index: 2;
        position: fixed;
    }

    .BoxLoad {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        margin-left: 15%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 1px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.8);
        color: #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size:24px;
    }

</style>


<body>

<div id="Background_1">
    <div id="Background_2">
        <div class="BoxLoad">
        </div>
        <div class="BoxLoad">
        </div>
        <div class="BoxLoad">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

on this source, we have 1 image on background (we can't see it) and 1 other (diff) image on it. and boxes on them. box have no background color and just have shadow with image 2 background. but what i need is to load background 1 as box background (part of background 1 not background 2) while background 1 still is under of back 2. it means if i create an other box anywhere of page with custom new settings, the background of that box was that point of back 1 image.
at the end i need something like this:
[End Image (What i want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlmRK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622143/is-it-possible-to-make-certain-parts-of-an-image-transparent-in-html5-css)

The main idea is to put same image (as in background) in Your "step 3 circles" and fix their position to be the same, as background's.

However, It's just simulates transpanence.

**Edit:** as mentioned @Mike Stringfellow in another answer, You can use SVG clipPath, but it requires HTML5 support.

Comment: is there better option to load (back image 1) one time? loading this image on each circle is heavy load if we want to have more than 1 circle !!!

Comment: Actually, the browser use caching and should load this image only once. You can check this in Network tab of Developer tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign an SVG clip path to your background image. Essentially, you build up the circles as below and then set the clip-path CSS property of the background div like so `clip-path: url(#circles);`

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="circles">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60" />
      <circle cx="300" cy="100" r="60" />
      <circle cx="500" cy="100" r="60" />
      <circle cx="200" cy="250" r="60" />
      <circle cx="400" cy="250" r="60" />
      <circle cx="600" cy="250" r="60" />
      <circle cx="300" cy="400" r="60" />
      <circle cx="500" cy="400" r="60" />
      <circle cx="700" cy="400" r="60" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hqss8taj/

Comment: i never used svg. at all if i want this (http://uupload.ir/files/daj4_49687-1920x1080.jpg) with same way. what source i have to use?

Comment: That's quite different to your first question. I wouldn't use a clip path at all for that, I'd simply put the bicycle image inside the outer div with the mountains background: https://jsfiddle.net/96grx7xz/

Comment: from my question, i want to reach something like i sent to you !! i want to create blur image and put it on first and second is non blur image of image 1 and ...

Comment: Thanks anyway. it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple divs for the circle and set the background image for the circle divs. Position the background image to get the desired position.
I have done for the first circle.
To differentiate the circle div with image to the end image you had attached I have used filter. Hope this is what you wanted.

```css
.circle{
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY480.jpg);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px red;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(200%);
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle1{
  top: 72px;
    left: 183px;
    background-position: -183px -72px;
}


.circle2{
  top: 152px;
    left: 183px;
    background-position: -183px -152px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlmRK.jpg">
  <div class="circle circle1"></div>
  <div class="circle circle2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there better option to load (back image 1) one time? loading this image on each circle is heavy load if we want to have more than 1 circle !!! other problem is background-position: -183px -72px; !!! on each circle we need to change this !!! kidding ? i need static code !!!

Comment: The image loads only once and applied as background to all divs

Comment: Thanks anyway. it was helpful